# Problems deploying ASP.NET MVC3 application on IIS 7 Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, web-deployment-project, webdeploy

I've just created a ASP.NET MVC3 application with a deployment package. In my IIS7.5 running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine I deployed the package, in a new site MySite. So, looking at the site tree, I have two nodes, MySite and Default Web Site. MySite  has a subnode called MyApplication (the one I have imported). The bindings of MySite are pointing to port 95.
ApplicationPoolIdentity is using a user login (administrator on the server) since the application need to impersonate a user. Everything is running well on the application identity side (I have checked this)
Now, when I try to access the application, I get the message "the adress is restricted" on my firefox browser. I type in http://myserver:95/MySite/MyApplication. 
The strange thing is that everything works on Windows 7! Are there some special security restrictions on Windows Server?
The signal is that accessing the Windows 7 adress I get the IIS7 welcome page, but this does not happen if I try to access the Windows server one. And the IIS on windows server is up and running since I'm hosting a TFS server which is working perfectly!
Any ideas?

Comment: The firewall is of course down for testing!

Comment: Have you installed the Authorizing policies in IIS ?

Comment: Authorization rules shows "Allow" on "All Users"

Comment: I mean, in IIS management console->authentication, which method do you have actually configured ? I've faced similar problems caused by the presence of windows authorization.

Comment: Everything is enable there as well.

Comment: enable only Windows authentication in IIS. Also try using IE for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another point:

I am able to negoiate with the hub in my silverlight client, if i use the dlls from : http://chris.59north.com/post/2011/12/15/SignalR-and-Silverlight.aspx After i replace all the dlls with the latest ones from the github, I am getting the error as mentioned above. Please note instead of Signalr.Client.SilverLight.dll, i am using Signalr.Client.SilverLight5.dll and the System.Threading.Tasks.SL5.dll.

This is the exact error, extracted it from fiddler

**

```
HttpException]: The controller for path '/MyVD/negotiate' was not found or does not implement IController.
 at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
 at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
 at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
 at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**

Thanks, Alpee